# c# and checkboxes in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hy all,

I want an idea from you.I have 2 tables.From table1 I want to populate a checkboxlist and from table2 I  want to also populate a checkboxlist but depending on the first checkboxlist.So if I have 5 rows in table1 then 5 checkbox. I want if I check the first checkbox some others checkbox appear with data from table2.So check a checkbox from table1 let's say for exemple 3 other checkboxes appear.So if I have a checkbox with country America when i check it 3 other checkboxes with California,Hawaii and Chicago to appear.Can you give me a point from where I can start? the tables are hooked up with ids that depend one another but I don't know how to make the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as 'master-detail view'. I've found one tutorial at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581796.aspx, but you may want to lookup more tutorials like this. Also, the tutorial uses a grid, but it's easy to bind a list box instead of a grid.